# Charset works on html but not on php pages

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have a dedicated server with Apache 1.3.42 and PHP 5.6.15. When I directly open an html file, charset works well with UTF-8. However, on my site I used to have a templates folder with all main pages in PHP. Then from PHP page call `include('page.html')`. However, even if I simple create PHP page only with

```
<?php
  include('templates/template.html')
?>
```

the charset doesn't work. But if I directly open `template.html` on my browser, charset works. I have set `default_charset` as UTF-8 in PHP and already tried to set it by using `.htaccess` without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saving file encoded in UTF-8 ?

Comment: That was the problem, thank you @ksno

Comment: I am glad to help you